# Design Pattern: How do I deal with different kinds of Organization?

Tags: design-patterns, web, database-schema

Say, I have different kinds of `Organization`, and I'm trying to use `Strategy Pattern`.

Here's what my Organization looks like:

```
Class Organization {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    // Do something common.
}
```

Since I have different kinds of Organization, and **every kind of Organization has its own fields**, e.g.:

```
Class School extends Organization {
    public String level;
    public String annuity;
    // Do something special for school.
}

Class Camp extends Organization {
    public String beginDate;
    public String endDate;
    // Do something special for Camp.
}
```

**There problem is:**
Now I need to design an admin panel for them, and I don't want to manage every kind of Organization individually.

**I want to manage all Organizations in only on page**.

So, How do I make it ?

And should I put all data into one table named `Organization` and add a `Type` field, or just create different tables for different Organizations ?

Comment: You need to explicit those "do something...". Without them I don't really see the need for strategy pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the use case for strategy pattern as you dont need any kind of algo/behaviour depending upon some situation.

Your 3 different classes does not look like they belong to same category as they have different fields altogether. To me this looks like something where you need to create the instances of different organisations and you should also know their type.

So first thing is find out if you can find the commonality between your classes. If yes get them implemented from an interface and get a factory class which would create each org depending upon some input parameter. 
If you can not find any commonality in your classes, then you should treat them all as different as they are no where related to each other.